# How to check in Alamofire for Errors

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My goal is it to make a progress view which appears to work but when those errors appear the value of the current download state goes beyond the actual value for Example "6mb/4mb".

These are my errors:

> [connection] nw_read_request_report [C555] Receive failed with error "Connection reset by peer"

and

> [tcp] tcp_input [C555:2] flags=[R] seq=214187986, ack=0, win=0 state=ESTABLISHED rcv_nxt=214187986, snd_una=3142070

I have no clue when those errors appear.

Here is my download function with Alamofire

```
Alamofire.download(downloadUrl, to: destination)
                        .downloadProgress { progress in
                            print("DOWNLOADURL: \(downloadUrl)")
                            completedUnit = completedUnit + (progress.completedUnitCount)
                            let completetValueFloat = Float(completedUnit)
                            let totalValueFloat = Float(calc)
                            let bytes =  Units(bytes: completedUnit).getReadableUnit()
                            let fullBytes = Units(bytes: calc).getReadableUnit()
                            if(progress.isFinished == false) {
                                self.backButton.isHighlighted = false
                            } else {
                                self.backButton.isHighlighted = true
                            }
                            let roundedValue = (completetValueFloat * 100) / totalValueFloat
                            self.Cells[indexPath.row].progressState = roundedValue / 100
                            self.Cells[indexPath.row].Percent = "\(bytes)/\(fullBytes) "
                            print("\(completedUnit):\(calc)")
                            print("Progress: \(roundedValue)")
                            self.table.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                        .response { response in
                            if response.error == nil {
                                
                            }
```

So my question is how I can check when those errors appear to subtract the Units from the Progress View.

Answer (score 0):

Those are system log spew that you can ignore. Simply handling the error you receive in the `response` value is enough.